# Capybara + Selenium inside Docker container

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium, capybara

I'm starting with integration tests and I'm using Docker on my dev env.

I have `selenium-webdriver` gem installed and this config file:

```
docker_ip = %x(/sbin/ip route|awk '/default/ { print $3 }').strip
Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app,
  :browser => :remote,
  :url => "http://#{docker_ip}:4444/wd/hub")
end

Capybara.app_host = "http://#{docker_ip}:3010"
Capybara.server_host = '0.0.0.0'
Capybara.server_port = '3011'
```

and when I run my integration test, it fails because I created a record with FactoryGirl (which creates on test DB) and my app (on port 3010) is running in dev env.
Capybara should starts by itself my app in test env?
What am I doing wrong?

PS: My app starts on dev end when I run `docker-compose up`

Comment: If you set Capybara.app_host, that's where Capybara is going to tell the browser to connect to. Therefore, if your dev env is running on port 3010 you shouldn't be setting app_host to port 3010

Comment: But if I don't set app_host I got a reached error, capybara can't connect to my app. How should it be?

Comment: app_host needs to be set the address that Capybara will run your app at.  Assuming I'm understanding what you're doing correctly (running the browser/selenium grid in docker, but capybara on your local machine) then `app_host` would be set to `http://#{the ip of your local machine accessible from docker}` and you would set `Capybara.always_include_port = true`

Comment: My capybara is also running inside Docker

Comment: If everything is being run in Docker, then you may not need to specify `app_host` at all, or potentially `http://#{docker_ip}` and set `Capybara.always_include_port = true` .  It needs to end up being an ip that resolves to one of the interfaces for whatever you've set Capybara.server_host to (in your case 0.0.0.0, which means all interfaces on the docker instance)

Comment: But my app will run at dev env, and capybara in test env. That's the problem I'm having. I don't know if I'm doing erything right.

Comment: By default Capybara runs it's own instance of your app at Capybara.server_host:Capybara.server_port, what your dev instance is being run at is irrelevant (unless you set app_host to point at your dev instance, which is just wrong)

Comment: If I comment the line `app_host` I got this error:

`Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError:
            Reached error page: about:neterror?e=connectionFailure`

Comment: And did you try setting apphost to `http://#{docker_ip}` and also setting `Capybara.always_include_port = true` as I suggested?

Comment: Now I have:

`Capybara.app_host = "http://#{docker_ip}"
Capybara.server_host = '0.0.0.0'
Capybara.server_port = '3011'

Capybara.always_include_port = true`

but I got the same error

Comment: Then there's something about your setup that you haven't explained fully, or you've changed other Capybara default settings -- As a last resort try setting Capybara.server_host to your docker ip, beyond that I have no idea what you're doing.

Comment: I have in my docker-compose
`selenium:
    image: selenium/standalone-firefox-debug:3.4.0
    ports:
      - 4444:4444
      - 5900:5900`

and in my Dockerfile

That's what I have

Comment: @jonatasdaniel Hi, did you solve your problem? I have a similar problem [on this SO question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44732620/rails-system-test-with-capybara-and-headless-selenium-browser-in-docker)

Comment: @SanjiBukai I didn't find any solution, then I moved to poltergeist rather then selenium.

Comment: @jonatasdaniel I finally found a [very good solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44746792/5121955)!

Comment: @SanjiBukai very interesting, I'll try this. Do you thin Selenium is better than poltergeist?

Answer (score 1):

In using docker-compose version 3,
this works for me

```
Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app,
  :browser => :remote,
  :url => "http://selenium:4444/wd/hub")
end

Capybara.app_host = "http://web:3010"
Capybara.server_host = '0.0.0.0'
Capybara.server_port = '3010'
Capybara.always_include_port = true
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - db
      - selenium
  ...
  selenium:
    image: selenium/standalone-firefox-debug:2.47.1
    ports:
      - "4444:4444"
  ...
```